# Php html парсер с полностью css подобным синтаксисом

Tags: php, парсер

Просмотрев популярные парсеры, увы они лишь частично поддерживают ccs-like синтаксис.
Некоторые примеры, которые не будут работать, может плохо искал

*.selector + span*

*.selector + .selector2  + b*

*.selector ~ .s2*

Ну и такие тоже иногда нужны, по типу jquery

*.selector:contains('some text')*

Кто нибудь встречал парсеры с таким ф-ционалом, про DomDocument конечно же знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#installation

Еще можно переводить в xpath https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html и через пэхэпешный xpath либо советую сразу xpath.

Comment: т.е. сразу xpath?

Comment: @rodigy на пыхе лучше xpath, правда он из коробки поддерживает старую версию, там не все фичи есть. Хотя щас может по иному, года 4 тому назад с ним последний раз дело имел.